# Creating a underline 'beneath' the text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a title where a line is 'beneath' the text as shown here
[image]

I'd look similar to a border-bottom, however I cannot figure how I'd move that by the text.

Thank you.

Comment: Use the browsers development console to examine the markup and the applied styles. That is all the information there is, the answer to your question is in there.

Comment: @arkascha it's a design I got made, otherwise I would use that. I'm trying to replicate a mockup in code form.

Comment: @Charlie using a pseudo element is probably your best bet

Comment: Thank you @Pete, any example of such? I thought about using a DIV, but I'd be a pain. Cheers

Comment: https://codepen.io/srirachachacha/pen/pNyQoY

Answer (score 3):

You can use pseudo class to generate the "border" and position it where you want.

```css
span {
  font-size: 3rem;
  position: relative;
}

span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: purple;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<span>Our Mission</span>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g1kdau57/